# jQuery Json and Each

Tags: jquery, json, each

There is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "?module=gestionApplication&action=importScenario&fichierconf="+$fichierconf,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function( data ) {


        $( "#dialog-scenario input#fichierxml" ).val( data.FICHIERXML );
        $( "#dialog-scenario input#fichierproxy" ).val( data.FICHIERPROXY );
        $( "#dialog-scenario select#portail" ).val( data.PORTAIL );
        $( "#dialog-scenario select#typemaj" ).val( data.MONITORING );
        $( "#dialog-scenario input#periodemaintenance" ).val( data.MAINT );
        $( "#dialog-scenario input#nomdns" ).val( data.DNSATESTER );
```

It works well, but i got like 40 lines of the same type is it possible to do the same action without knowing the string after data. ?

I would do something like

```
data.each( function(dataName) {
   $( "#dialog-scenario inputORselect#"+dataName ).val( data.dataname );
});
```

Thx for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a map between the name of the element and the data property:

```
var map,
    prop;

map = {
    "typemaj" : "MONITORING",
    "periodemaintenance" : "MAINT"
}
```

Then you can loop through the properties to set their values.

```
for( prop in map ) {
    $( "#dialog-scenario inputORselect#" + prop ).val( data[ map[prop] ] );
}
```

Comment: I keep forgetting about maps in favour of `$.each` this is probably more efficient. Nice solution Bruno.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    // do your processing here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, keep in mind that an id is always unique and doesn't need information about it's parent.

```
$.each(data, function(name, value) {
   $("#"+name.toLowerCase()).val(value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function( data ) {
    $.each(data, function(i, dataName) {
       $( "#dialog-scenario inputORselect#"+dataName ).val( data.dataname );
    });
}
```